# Any known solutions for Image Differencing in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing, actionscript, kinect

I'm working with a few programming buddies to create an AS interface to the kinect and one problem we're running into is image differencing.  We need to be able to throw out image data that doesn't change from image to image so we can pin-point only things that are moving(i.e. people).

Anyone have any experience with this or a direction we can go?

Comment: have a look at this example: http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/actionscript-3/webcam-motion-detection-tracking too

Comment: Bascially there are two bitmapData instances drawn from the webcam, the current and the previous one. The current one draws using BlendMode.DIFFERENCE...so only the pixels that are changed show up then, after using threshold,getColorBoundsRect is used to get a Rectangle object of the 'moving' pixels. If the rectangle has an area large enough (enough pixels change) then that is considered activity/movement. You can access all that easily through MotionTracker.hasMovement;

Comment: awesome, thanks for the suggestions!  I'll be looking into it more tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah we're using very similar techniques, and one thing to point out is we also have a depth camera we're utilizing for blob detection. That's a different problem we're going to have to deal with along side the image differencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider creating a pixel bender shader to find the difference and also do any other math or tracking. Pixel bender gets its own thread outside of the normal flash player so you can get some more horse power for your setup. Pixel Bender shaders can be applied to bitmaps, vectors, or video so I think it is perfect for this project. Good Luck!

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/pixel_bender_basics.html

[And is is a full collection of shaders including difference](http://www.jamesward.com/2009/04/29/announcing-pbjas-an-actionscript-3-pixel-bender-shader-library/)

Comment: great suggestion, thanks!  we're still trying to figure out blob detection too with the depth camera.  have to keep this in mind...

Comment: Just a random idea.... Could you turn the depth data into a grayscale height map and then use a color range/difference to find what you are looking for?

Comment: Having its own thread would make this the ideal way to go. I might have to look into Pixel Bender; I've never heard of it before!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [**threshold**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#threshold%28%29) method on BitmapData.
It'll allow you to do this stuff. Their docs have a simple example so check that out.

Comment: We looked into using Threshold and it's going to be good for figuring out which things are moving(i.e. blob detection), but frame to frame background differencing threshold wouldn't work well because with the type of images we're getting any objects in front of the object we're trying to get at would disrupt the image. There's a few other situations as well.  We do need both though to get this to work, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It might be a long shot, and this is just me rambling, but in sound theory (strange how I'm relating it to image cancellation, but here goes...) the concept of cancellation is when you take a wave sample and add its inverse. It's how you make acapellas from instrumentals + originals or instrumentals from acapellas + originals.

Perhaps you can invert the new image and "normalize" the two to get your offsets? I.e. the first image is 'black on white' and the second image is 'white on black', and then detect the differences for the bitmap data. I know I did a similar method of finding collisions with AS3 a few years back. This would, in theory, cancel out any 'repeating' pixels and leave you with just the changes from the last frame.

With BitmapData your values are going to be from 0 to 255, so if you can implement a cancellation (because a lot of parts of the image are going to stay the same from frame t frame) then you can easily find the changes from the previous frame.

Just a thought! Whatever your solution is it's going to have to be quick in order to beat the flash runtimes' slow speeds. Your Kinect read FPS rate will be greatly hindered with bad code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some frame differencing code I wrote awhile back. It uses bitmapData: http://actionsnippet.com/?p=2820

I also used this to capture moving colors in a video feed: http://actionsnippet.com/?p=2736